# How to set a class or module attribute in a patchmonkey in py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixture

I'm starting a small project in Python and I want to create a unittest with py.test.
I need to patch a `pymongo` module or a `MongoClient` class.
So I tried something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def mock_pymongo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('pymongo', mongomock)
```

or somthing like this :

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def mock_pymongo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient', mongomock.mongo_client.MongoClient)
```

now in both test I am doing I get a scope mismatch error

```
scopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'monkeypatch' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories
tests/test_1.py:17:  def mock_pymongo(monkeypatch)
```

Maybe I'm using the right tool
but is there any way using monkeypatch in order to mock class and module in my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` argument doesn't specifiy what to patch - it specifies the lifetime of the fixture. With the default scope (`module`), the patching will happen before each test, and be reverted after the test. That's generally the behavior you want.